# Something happens to graphics when cisco webex is opened

Tags: windows, graphics, cisco-webex

When cisco webex training session is running (It is open in another workspace. That is why not shown in the screenshot), windows behaves like that when there is no graphic driver installed in windows 7 in olden days. When we drag the window, only a rectangle follows. The picture shows what happens when I drag the title bar.

Why is this happening?

[image]